# jQuery string escape onclick='deleteRow(item"+count+")' how to quote around item and count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't even know how to ask this question correctly, I tried to put quotes around a part of my string however it always break.

I am creating html dynamically and I am encountering error when I try to do this:

```
onclick='deleteRow("item"+count+"")'
```

I am trying to pass `item1` as a string to a `deleteRow` function however best I could do is pass it like this `deleteRow(item1)` with no quotes. I am not sure how to escape them so that they would show.

This line of code is generated inside my JavaScript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use jQuery event handlers instead of inline one..

But in this case the below should do it

```
"onclick='deleteRow(\"item"+count + "\")'"
```

Comment: That works I tried that, but I must have used all single quotes.. I could never get it to work. Thanks!